# Adding Session Variable in C# using Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I need to add variable into session state using ajax , when I tries this It didn't work. can any one please help me on this. when I  click the Button It redirect to Travellerinfo.aspx page

Below is my test.aspx

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="hotelbeds.test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Tooltip - Custom animation demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testbook(hotelcode) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.aspx/addSession",
            data: "{'hotelcode':'" + hotelcode + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                window.location.href = "Hotelresul.aspx";
            },
            error: function (err) {
                window.location.href = "TravellerInfo.aspx";
            }
        });

    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

CS test.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;

namespace hotelbeds
{

    public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs ea)
        {
            ImageButton testbtn = new ImageButton();
            testbtn.OnClientClick = "testbook('15000')";
            form1.Controls.Add(testbtn);

        }
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static void addSession(String hotelcode)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("hotelcode", hotelcode);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You should debug into the `addSession` method (set breakpoint) and check if it's excuted. And make it a `public` accessor.

Comment: You can keep WebMethod inside an .aspx page. But the method must be public and static. See my answer. @RGraham

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It must be

```
[WebMethod (EnableSession=true)]
        public static void addSession(String hotelcode)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("hotelcode", hotelcode);

        }
```

Please Note: The method must be public, static and [EnableSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.enablesession.aspx) attribute must be true.

EDIT 1:

'return false' is added to prevent the Default function of a button. The default function of a button is to post form to server. Alternatively, [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) can be used to prevent the default functionality.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testbook(hotelcode) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.aspx/addSession",
            data: "{'hotelcode':'" + hotelcode + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                window.location.href = "Hotelresul.aspx";
            },
            error: function (err) {
                window.location.href = "TravellerInfo.aspx";
            }
        });


 return false;

    }

</script>
```

EDIT 2:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs ea)
        {
            ImageButton testbtn = new ImageButton();
            testbtn.OnClientClick = "return testbook('15000')";
            form1.Controls.Add(testbtn);

        }
```

Comment: please press ctrl+shift+J from your browser (chrome) and chose console tab. After executing (ie clicking the button) the code please Quote the error reported.

Comment: I did try that also, still no luck

Comment: Run your Project (press F5). After executing this ajax call, from visual studio > debug> view intelli trace events> expand the last exception caught and see  the error.

Comment: added 'return' to onClientClick and returned false to your javaScript function. This should work. please check the updated answer.

Comment: You are welcome ! 'return false' is added to prevent the Default function of a button. The default function of a button is to post form to server. Alternatively, event.preventDefault() can be used to prevent the default functionality. http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/